# Continue dates on a data frame in r

Tags: r, date, dataframe

Let say I have the following `data.frame`:

```
Dates<-seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), by = 'day', length.out = 365)
A <- data.frame(date=(Dates), month=month(Dates), week=week(Dates))
library(dplyr)
B <- A %>% dplyr::mutate(day = lubridate::wday(date, label = TRUE))
B[350:365,]

          date month week day
350 2017-12-16    12   50 Sat
351 2017-12-17    12   51 Sun
352 2017-12-18    12   51 Mon
353 2017-12-19    12   51 Tue
354 2017-12-20    12   51 Wed
355 2017-12-21    12   51 Thu
356 2017-12-22    12   51 Fri
357 2017-12-23    12   51 Sat
358 2017-12-24    12   52 Sun
359 2017-12-25    12   52 Mon
360 2017-12-26    12   52 Tue
361 2017-12-27    12   52 Wed
362 2017-12-28    12   52 Thu
363 2017-12-29    12   52 Fri
364 2017-12-30    12   52 Sat
365 2017-12-31    12   53 Sun
```

I need to add another ten dates after the end date which is from  2018-01-01 to 2018-01-10. Sequence for week should be continuous. For example:

```
           date month week day
 365 2017-12-31    12   53 Sun
 366 2018-01-01     1   53 Mon
 367 2018-01-02     1   53 Tue
 368 2018-01-03     1   53 Wed
 369 2018-01-04     1   53 Thu
 370 2018-01-05     1   53 Fri
 371 2018-01-06     1   53 Sat
 372 2018-01-07     1   54 Sun
 373 2018-01-08     1   54 Mon
 374 2018-01-09     1   54 Tue
 375 2018-01-10     1   54 Wed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Dates<-seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), by = 'day', length.out = 365)
A <- data.frame(date=(Dates), month=month(Dates), week=week(Dates))

B <- A %>% dplyr::mutate(day = lubridate::wday(date, label = TRUE))
B[350:365,]


B %>%
  rbind(                                                                    # bind rows with the following dataset     
    data.frame(date = seq(max(B$date)+1, by = 'day', length.out = 10)) %>%  # create sequence of new dates
      mutate(month = month(date),                                           # add month
             day = wday(date, label = TRUE),                                # add day
             week = cumsum(day=="Sun") + max(A$week)) ) %>%                 # add week: continuous from last week of A and gets updated every Sunday
  tbl_df()                                                                  # only for visualisation purposes


# # A tibble: 375 x 4
#   date       month  week day  
#   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <ord>
# 1 2017-01-01     1     1 Sun  
# 2 2017-01-02     1     1 Mon  
# 3 2017-01-03     1     1 Tue  
# 4 2017-01-04     1     1 Wed  
# 5 2017-01-05     1     1 Thu  
# 6 2017-01-06     1     1 Fri  
# 7 2017-01-07     1     1 Sat  
# 8 2017-01-08     1     2 Sun  
# 9 2017-01-09     1     2 Mon  
#10 2017-01-10     1     2 Tue  
# # ... with 365 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you. I had extract the output. Actually, I need the week to be continuous. I will edit on my questions.

Comment: Check again. I've change the logic of `week` creation for the extra dates. It should work now.

Comment: I've check and it send me this error: 
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: unused argument (label = TRUE).

Comment: Do you get the error when you run my example or in your full dataset?

Comment: in my dataset @AntoniosK

Comment: If my example works, then you have to find out what is the difference between your full dataset and the example you provided. Maybe you just have to restart R and work on a new session. You might have some functions conflict from different packages.

Answer (score 1):

Little Tweak to @antoniosk code , just added max of week from the past data frame and got the continuous week numbers as desired.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Dates<-seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), by = 'day', length.out = 365)
A <- data.frame(date=(Dates), month=month(Dates), week=week(Dates))

B <- A %>% dplyr::mutate(day = lubridate::wday(date, label = TRUE))
B[350:365,]


c<- B %>%   rbind(                                                                       # bind rows with the following dataset
data.frame(date = seq(max(B$date)+1, by = 'day', length.out = 10)) %>% # get 10 extra sequential dates after the last date in B
mutate(month = month(date), week = (as.numeric(strftime(date, format = "%U")) +max(A$week)),day = wday(date, label = TRUE)) ) %>% tbl_df()
```

Comment: Check again your output :) It has only 1 row as `week = 53` and your weeks go up to `55`.

Comment: @AntoniosK week 53 ends on Sunday 31st December 2017, so Monday is week 54 . I think gizmo can tell whether is this what he wants or not ?

Comment: Based on what he posted above week 54 should start on Sunday. Week column seems to change on Sundays (check the last part of his question above).

Comment: It should be like what @AntoniosK said. I need the week to change on every sunday

Comment: @gizmo please check the updated code i have made some necessary changes and weeks are now coming in continuous fashion

Comment: Thanks @Hunaidkhan